# How does skewness in the independent features affect the performance of classification algorithms?

Tags: classification, skewness, transform

Do we need to take action when we encounter a skewed feature (not the target)? We can log transform for regression etc., but does it matter in also classification models?

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! What do you mean by skewness in a classification model? Do you mean an imbalance of classes?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: No, I meant another feature, not the target. For example, I want to classify the obesity levels (classes are somewhat balanced) and I have a highly skewed weight feature (which is float). Do I need to take action on this weight feature?